# Why we use various layers in OLED (ETL,EIL,HTL,HIL)? How they increase efficiency OLED device?

Tags: physical-organic-chemistry

Currently, I am studying the working of OLED devices! The device can work with just three layers which are Anode, Cathode and Emission layers. I know the fact that the work function is an important parameter in the device. I have read articles about Various layers which can we add in devices to increase the overall performance of the device.

The layers we add for improving efficiency are as follows

1. EIL (Electron Injection layer)
2. ETL (Electron transfer layer)
3. HIL (hole injection layer)
4. HTL (hole transfer layer)

I know the fact that To overcome losses in devices, a step-wise energy transport architecture is used, and the work function of layers are in between the emission layer and electrodes.

My question is How those layers can help in increasing efficiency? Why do we use them?
I need a detailed explanation of this question with proper work function values
[image]

Comment: The question is (perhaps too much) influenced by the view of cells built layer-by-layer (e.g., cathode, electron acceptor, electron donor, the transparent anode) where two in the middle total for about ~100 nm. But excitons in OLEDs die quickly, and must be split within ~10 nm of travel, one reason favouring ordered (stacked comb-like) hetero bulkjunction cells, or (simpler, e.g., spray coating produced) disordered hetero bulkjunction cells. The optimization of OSOLs isn't only optimization of the components (e.g., crystallinity vs. density of traps); a simple brief answer here won't fit.